# On what follows "prerequisite"

Tags: prepositions, verbs

I have some doubts on the idioms employing "prerequisite". Take this example:

> A is not a prerequisite of/for/to B

1. According to dictionaries, prerequisite can be followed by the 3 prepositions of/for/to. Can I use the 3 prepositions interchangeably? If not, what is the difference/rule?
2. If B begins with a verb, should it be an infinitive verb or an -ing verb? Should I use an infinitive or -ing verb depending on the preposition that I use? I have seen examples of the preposition "to" followed by both infinitive and -ing verbs, so I don't know what the rule is. I am even wondering whether both infinitive and -ing verbs can be correct in this particular case.

Thanks.

Comment: of : for : to :: noun : participle : infinitive

Comment: I think the headline takeaway here is you should only use an actual infinitive after the prepositional *phrase* "in order to". The "preposition + infinitive" form [*a prerequisite **to watch** {HDTV is expensive hardware}}*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+prerequisite+to+watch%22) does occur, but it's quite rare compared to "preposition + gerund" *(prerequisite **to watching...**)*, which is the preferred version.

Answer (score 1):

[This NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prerequisite+of%2Cprerequisite+for%2Cprerequisite+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprerequisite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprerequisite%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprerequisite%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows relative frequency of occurrence for all three prepositions following ***prerequisite***.

[image]

Three separate "wildcard" NGram searches for "prerequisite **[of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prerequisite%20of%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20successful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20good%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20success%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20successful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20of%20good%3B%2Cc0) [for](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prerequisite%20for%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20for%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20admission%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20successful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20voting%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20for%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20this%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20admission%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20successful%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20such%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20for%20voting%3B%2Cc0) [to](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prerequisite%20to%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20voting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20obtaining%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20such%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20to%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20any%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20all%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20an%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20voting%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20its%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20their%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20obtaining%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20to%20such%3B%2Cc0)**" ALL show the SAME three "most common following words" *in the same order* for each preposition *(**the, a, any**)*.

Note that *prerequisite **to*** has ***voting*** and ***obtaining*** as the 7th and 8th most common words following ***to***, and ***...for*** has ***voting*** in 10th place. Those are the only instances of (gerund) verbs.

Also note that although the charts show no instances off a gerund verb being in the "top ten" for ***of*** (only ***to*** and ***for***), these are only *relative usage tendencies*. As [this Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22prerequisite%20of%20voting%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALiCzsZGAGaHAWospGRHL8wJbr-KVTPGZQ:1667908498257&ei=kkNqY5CTD6KBhbIPw4O4qAw&start=90&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiQpLmsw577AhWiQEEAHcMBDsUQ8tMDegQIDxAU&biw=1408&bih=668&dpr=1.36) shows, there are many instances of *prerequisite **of** voting* from published writers over the years.

Although there are no instances of *prerequisite **[to verb]*** in any of my above searches (where ***to*** is an infinitive marker, not a preposition), the format *does* occur occasionally *(church attendance is not a **prerequisite to go** to heaven)*, but it's not common (it's usually [*prerequisite **for going** to heaven*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prerequisite%20for%20going%20to%20heaven%22) anyway).

---

TL;DR: The infinitive verb form is rarely used after ***prerequisite*** - but if it *is*, *no preposition is included*. Other than that, usage isn't really consistent enough to justify worrying about choice of preposition - but if you *need* a guiding principle, just use the current favorite ***for*** in all contexts.

FINALLY: See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20obtain%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20be%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20achieve%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20avoid%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20make%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20determine%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20establish%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20understand%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bprerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20have%3B%2Cc0) for ***in order to*** (a *prepositional phrase*) showing the most common verbs following as ***be, achieve, understand, make, avoid, determine, obtain, establish, have***. Given that ***voting*** is the only gerund to appear in more than one "single-word preposition" context, I can't explain why [*prerequisite in order to **vote***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prerequisite%20in%20order%20to%20vote%22) doesn't occur more often. I just take that as further evidence that there aren't many meaningfully consistent usage patterns in this general area.

Comment: Wow, what a detailed answer. Thank you very much! To summarise and to be sure that I understand you well, this is my takeaway: 1) Use FOR, 2) If need be to use a verb, use FOR + GERUND. Right?

Comment: Absolutely! And if you *really* want to use an infinitive verb, only use it after the prepositional phrase ***in order to***. Offhand I can't say for certain whether ***to*** there is in fact a preposition (or an "infinitive marker")  (But if I as a native speaker don't know that, you as a learner probably don't need to know it either! :)

Comment: The words "the", "a" and "any" aren't "prepositions". Did you mean "determiners"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I have a question. If we use the example discussed in the other thread (https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326984/on-generalising-statements) with your rule stated in the present thread, we would use for+gerund: **A college degree is not a prerequisite for having/getting a good job.** However, according to your rule in the other thread, we would have to use to+infinitive: **A college degree is not a prerequisite to have/get a good job**. What should be used in this case and why? Thanks.

Comment: @gotube: Perhaps my phrasing isn't ideal, but what I meant there was *for each of the three prepositions under consideration* *(**for, to, of**)* I did a wildcard search for the next word AFTER ***prerequisite [for|to|of]***. In every case the three most common words (in the same "popularity" sequence) were the determiners  ***the, a, any***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Got it. You might want to clear up that ambiguity. I think the result merits its own non-parenthetical clause, but that's just me